# fill one columns' value with a part of other's column repeatedly with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new data frame as following:

```
   Facility YEAR_MONTH

0   'A' May 2019 

1   'A' Jun 2019 

...

11  'A'  Apr 2020 

12  'B' May 2019

13  'B' Jun 2019    
...

23  'B'  Apr 2020
```

the original data frame is

```
columns_list=['May 2019',
             'Jun 2019',
             'Jul 2019',
             'Aug 2019',
             'Sep 2019',
             'Oct 2019',
             'Nov 2019',
             'Dec 2019',
             'Jan 2020',
             'Feb 2020',
             'Mar 2020',
             'Apr 2020']
Year_Month = pd.DataFrame(columns_list,columns=['Column_Name'])
Year_Month
```

```
facility=['A','B']
```

Below is the way how I did: 
I wish I could create a function to get my result, but it doesn't work(so I delete the way to append the YEAR_MONTH)

```
# create a function to get the new format of the data
def build_df(df_target):
    temp_df=df_target.copy()
    for i in range(0,len(facility)):
        temp_df=temp_df.append({
               'Facility':facility[i],
               }, ignore_index=True)
    return temp_df
df1=build_df(df1)
df1
```

I also tried, but failed

```
df1[(df1['Facility']==facility[0])]['YEAR_MONTH']=Year_Month['Column_Name']
df1
```

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertool.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(product(columns_list,['A','B']),columns=['Column','Facility'])
# df = pd.DataFrame(product(columns_list,['A','B']),columns=['Column','Facility']).sort_values('Column')
# To get sorted values by 'Column'.

      Column   Facility
0   May 2019      A
1   May 2019      B
2   Jun 2019      A
3   Jun 2019      B
4   Jul 2019      A
5   Jul 2019      B
6   Aug 2019      A
7   Aug 2019      B
8   Sep 2019      A
9   Sep 2019      B
10  Oct 2019      A
11  Oct 2019      B
12  Nov 2019      A
13  Nov 2019      B
14  Dec 2019      A
15  Dec 2019      B
16  Jan 2020      A
17  Jan 2020      B
18  Feb 2020      A
19  Feb 2020      B
20  Mar 2020      A
21  Mar 2020      B
22  Apr 2020      A
23  Apr 2020      B
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create dataframe using a dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
columns_list=['May 2019','Jun 2019','Jul 2019','Aug 2019','Sep 2019','Oct 2019','Nov 2019','Dec 2019','Jan 2020','Feb 2020','Mar 2020','Apr 2020']
repeat = len(columns_list)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Facility':list('A'*repeat+'B'*repeat),'YEAR_MONTH':columns_list*2})

>>>print(df)
   Facility YEAR_MONTH
0         A   May 2019
1         A   Jun 2019
2         A   Jul 2019
3         A   Aug 2019
4         A   Sep 2019
5         A   Oct 2019
6         A   Nov 2019
7         A   Dec 2019
8         A   Jan 2020
9         A   Feb 2020
10        A   Mar 2020
11        A   Apr 2020
12        B   May 2019
13        B   Jun 2019
14        B   Jul 2019
15        B   Aug 2019
16        B   Sep 2019
17        B   Oct 2019
18        B   Nov 2019
19        B   Dec 2019
20        B   Jan 2020
21        B   Feb 2020
22        B   Mar 2020
23        B   Apr 2020
```